# How to add CSS to an if else statement in PHP

Tags: php, css

I would like to change the colour of my status text based on if it is accepted (green), or rejected (red). Currently, they give values of "1" being accepted or "2" being rejected.

How can I change the colour of this based on the outcome.

Here is my PHP:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `REQUESTS` ORDER BY $selectOption"; 
echo $query;
$result = $db->query($query);
if ($result == FALSE){ 
    die ("could not execute statement $query<br />");
} else {
    echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
    echo "<table>";                         
    while($row=$result->fetchRow()){                        
        echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it applying different css classes depending on the state.

**CSS:**

```
td.status-accepted{color:green;}
td.status-rejected{color:red;}
```

**HTML/PHP:**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `REQUESTS` ORDER BY $selectOption"; 
echo $query;
$result = $db->query($query);
if ($result == FALSE){ 
    die ("could not execute statement $query<br />");
} else {
    echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
    echo "<table>";                         
    while($row=$result->fetchRow()){                        
    echo '<td class="'.(($row['status'] == 2) ? 'status-rejected' : 'status-accepted'). '">'.$row['status'].'</td>';
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
```

By :

```
echo "<td style='color: ".(($row['status'] == 2) ? 'red' : 'green')."'>".$row['status'].'</td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two divs with the settings.

Set the reject div around reject message and accept div around the accept div.

Not sure I understand the problem here.

EDIT:

Sorry, I understand now that Status is the reject/accepted. I thought it was $Result

Answer (score -1):

You can add a `style` attribute to the `<td>` like this,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `REQUESTS` ORDER BY $selectOption"; 
echo $query;
$result = $db->query($query);
if ($result == FALSE){ 
    die ("could not execute statement $query<br />");
} else {
    echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
    echo "<table>";                         
    while($row=$result->fetchRow()){

        $style = $row['status'] == 1 ? 'green' : 'red';
        echo "<td style='color:$style'>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>"; 
}
```

Now is you had a CSS class's already defined called `text-red` and `text-green` you could use this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `REQUESTS` ORDER BY $selectOption"; 
echo $query;
$result = $db->query($query);
if ($result == FALSE){ 
    die ("could not execute statement $query<br />");
} else {
    echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
    echo "<table>";                         
    while($row=$result->fetchRow()){

        $class= $row['status'] == 1 ? 'text-green' : 'text-red';
        echo "<td class='$class'>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>"; 
}
```